# UWP app: insert / remove user control MVVM way

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, template10

I'm learning UWP at the moment in an attempt to port an old Win32 to the new platform. I'm using Template10 and everything runs fine so far, except I'm bit confused on how to implement the problem below.

**Problem**: In a page, I have to constantly remove and insert user controls depending on a view model property. The user controls are fairly complex and they all look and behave differently. Imagine a wizard with back and next buttons. On every click I have to remove the old content and insert a new one, with completely different view model.

**Question**: What would be the recommended way of implementing this in a MVVM way?

At the moment, my only idea is to send a message from the page's view model and subscribe for the message in page's code behind where I can create the required component and insert it dynamically in the page (after removing the old one).

In MyPageViewModel:

```
public IComponentViewModel CurrentComponent {get; set;}
...
public DelegateCommand NextItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
    var evt = App.EventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemChangedMessage>();
    evt.Publish(CurrentComponent);
});
```

In MyPage.xaml.cs code behind

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var evt = App.EventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemChangedMessage>();
    evt.Subscribe(OnItemChanged);
}

private void OnItemChanged(IComponentViewModel viewModel)
{
    switch (viewModel.Type)
    {
        case 1:
            // create the new user control and insert it in the container
            var component = new TypeOneComponent();
            component.DataContext = (TypeOneCompoentViewModel)viewModel;
            // ...
        case 2:
            ...
     }
}
```

Not sure this is the best approach tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about a Wizard approach lately myself. It seems to me that a `FlipView` with re-templated left/right buttons is the easiest approach. My WizardViewModel would have several children view-models; something like Page1ViewModel, Page2ViewModel, and so on. I *strongly* feel that each page view-model would have a dedicated `UserControl` so the UI can be unique but not dynamic - I think it makes sense to design against dynamic UI, while embracing an adaptive UI - which is a different concept altogether.

The pseudo code might look like this:

```
public interface IWizardPage { }

public class Page1ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IWizardPage { }
public class Page2ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IWizardPage { }
public class Page3ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IWizardPage { }

public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IWizardPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public IWizardPage Page1ViewModel { get; set; }
    public IWizardPage Page2ViewModel { get; set; }
    public IWizardPage Page3ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

And this:

```
<FlipView Template="{StaticResource WizardFlipView}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Page1UserControl DataContext="{Binding Page1ViewModel}" />
    <Page2UserControl DataContext="{Binding Page2ViewModel}" />
    <Page3UserControl DataContext="{Binding Page3ViewModel}" />
</FlipView>
```

This is just a recommendation. But to answer your question, this would be very amenable to the MVVM pattern. I also think this would allow for you to be very flexible without getting so dynamic that maintenance is affordably time consuming. There are lots of ways to do wizards. I think this would be a fine solution, good with the MVVM pattern and fine with Template 10.

Best of luck.

Comment: I really like this approach - clean and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use an ItemsControl. This allows you to have a generic item template and a item specific template if you want and you can add / remove items at will by binding to the ItemsSource.

In your example of a wizard, you might make the main wizard container an ItemsControl that only shows one item at a time and a page would be an "item". The distinction with MVVM is that you don't add child *controls*, you add *data* and then specify a template to render it. So your items are going to be simple databound poco objects.

For your actual example, I guess you can add child controls to the ItemsControl and they would render automatically without even using a template since a ContentPresenter knows how to render controls. I would still use data only classes though since one of the tenants of MVVM is to separate the data from the UI. So your child item would be a model and your item specific template would be the UI layout bound to the item data.

Comment: The problem is that the different components should implement fairly complex logic. For example, there will be a component that should allow the user to drag and drop different elements, other component with completely different set of elements allowing the user to add and reorder elements in a list, etc. My feeling that this logic should be somehow encapsulated within a UserControl. Right?

Comment: @JulianKolev, my own person taste, but if I have complex UI functionality, I break that part into a reusable UserControl, but I make it completely independent of any business logic. It should be packaged so you can stick it in any other project with zero changes. So lets say your user control has a special grid for d&d... I would create a MyDragNDropGrid user control and put ONLY UI logic in it and make it like a real control where all the properties are bindable. That makes it easier to just bind a simple model to it in the MVVM pattern.

Comment: indeed, I want the components to be completely independent with their own views and login in the code behind. That's not a problem. What I'm not clear is where/how to swap them in the container depending on a view model property of the containing page.

Comment: @JulianKolev, If you only want to show one at a time then make your main container a ContentPresenter and replace the Content. Many ways to switch... a trigger in the view, a property in the VM, etc. If you structure your naming well, you don't even need a switch or anything. You can make your naming convention Views\UserControl1.xaml UserControl2.xaml, etc. And then build the path based on the other property. Or you can do what a tab control does and add all the views to a TabControl (hide the tabs visually) and then set the active page based on an int property. Like I said, many ways :).